# Get all rows apart from first and last

Tags: mysql, sql

What MySQL query would get me all the rows where `booking_id=1`, but omit the first and last row?

This can be determined by looking at the `sequence` column, 0 is always the first row, but the last row varies - in this case it is 4 but it can be 2,3,6,etc...

I've build a sample schema in [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b9abca)

Code:

```
CREATE TABLE waypoint 
    (
     id int auto_increment primary key, 
     booking_id varchar(11), 
     sequence varchar(11),
     address varchar(300)
    );
INSERT INTO waypoint
(booking_id, sequence, address)
VALUES
('1', '0', 'MK9 1AN,Santander,Santander Uk Plc,Santander House,201,Grafton Gate East'),
('1', '1', 'MK13 0DD,4,Glyn Street,New Bradwell,Milton Keynes,'),
('1', '2', 'MK6 2DU,65,Towan Avenue,Fishermead,Milton Keynes,'),
('1', '3', 'MK1 1LG,10a,Clarke Road,Bletchley,Milton Keynes,'),
('1', '4', 'MK11 1BJ,3,York Road,Stony Stratford,Milton Keynes');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the query which returns desired result:

```
SELECT * FROM waypoint 
WHERE ID NOT IN(
    (SELECT MIN(ID) FROM waypoint WHERE booking_id="1"), 
    (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM waypoint WHERE booking_id="1")
  )
AND booking_id="1";
```

This query computes mimimum and maximum `ID` from waypoints with `booking_id="1"`. Then these id's are excluded from result set (`NOT IN` clause)

Answer (score 1):

Use MIN and MAX functions. [FIDDLER DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b9abca/3)

```
SELECT * FROM waypoint 
WHERE ID NOT IN(
        (SELECT MIN(ID) FROM waypoint), 
        (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM waypoint)
      )
```

Comment: Sorry it doesn't seem to be working well. The result should be id rows 2,3,4 but I am getting 2,3,4 and 5 - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/82f84/4